# citation also in footnote

Tags: biblatex, footnotes

I'm trying to have a citation (`\cite{something}`) appear in the footnote as well.

I've tried doing this by adding `\foonote{}\cite{}` to stuff, but it became weird.

`\usepackage[style=footnote-dw]{biblatex}` is also weird, as it just displays the label of the citation in the footnote.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what is meant??  The `bibentry` package allows the actual citation text to be grabbed with `\bibentry{<label>}`, so that it can be inserted into a footnote, for example.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{bibentry}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{mytestbib.bib}
@book{goossens93,
    author = "Frank Mittelbach and Michel Goossens  and Johannes Braams and David Carlisle  and Chris Rowley",
    title = "The {LaTeX} Companion",
    year = "1993",
    publisher = "Addison-Wesley",
    address = "Reading, Massachusetts"
}
@ARTICLE{segl03,
        AUTHOR  = "Segletes, S. B. AND Walters, W. P.",
        TITLE = {Extensions to the Exact Solution of the Long-Rod
                 Penetration/Erosion Equations},
        JOURNAL = "IJIE",
        YEAR    = "2003",
        VOLUME  = "28",
        PAGES   = "363--376"}
\end{filecontents}
\nobibliography*
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\begin{document} 
Citing these references in the main text.\cite{goossens93, segl03}%
\footnote{\cite{goossens93} \bibentry{goossens93}}.
I can then access both the number of the cite as well as the full citation, 
shown here in the footnote.

Now here is the bibliography.

\bibliography{mytestbib}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: do you know how to make that work with biblatex? the \bibentry doesn't seem to work.

Comment: @David天宇Wong I am not a `biblatex` user, but if you edit your question to post a full working example that demonstrates the problem, perhaps I or someone else could take a stab.

Comment: looks like \fullcite is the biblatex equivalent.

Comment: @David天宇Wong Great!  Perhaps you can post your own answer showing how to access that.